# Flask getlist always empty

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to add checkboxes so I can delete multiple records from a database. I give multiple inputs the same `name`, but `request.form.getlist` returns an empty list even if some boxes are checked.

```html
{% for order in orders %}
<input type="checkbox" name="select_button" value="{{ order.order_id }}">
{% endfor %}
```

```
@mod_order.route('_delete_multiple_confirmation', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def delete_multiple_orders_confirmation():
    orders = (request.form.getlist('select_button'))
    user_id = request.args.get('user_id')
    response_context = {'orders': orders, 'user_id': user_id}
    return render_template('delete_multiple_order_confirmation.html', **response_context)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This one knocked me down for hours !!
Hoping this post can help people save time.

When you give multiple inputs, then your input type get implicitly changed into an array. 
This means you have to extract the result from an array.
You do that by adding this 2 characters at the end of the name of your input variable "[]" :

in your case we get:
orders = (request.form.getlist('select_button[]'))

---

fullstack example:

==>in your html using bootstrap

```
<select class="selectpicker" multiple title="input list" id="inputlist">
<option>input1</option>
<option>input2</option>
<option>input3</option>
</select>
<small>Click Go! to proceed : </small>
<button class="myConfirmButton btn btn-primary">Go!</button>
<small><div id="myFeedback"></div></small>
```

==>in your jquery/javascript

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".myConfirmButton").click(function(){
// this line creates the array of all the checked inputs 
var values = $('#listinput').val()
  $.ajax({
    url:"/processlist",
    dataType:'html',
    type:'post',
    contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    data : {
       listinput: values
    },
    success: function( data ){
    $('#myFeedback').html( data );
  },
    error: function( errorThrown ){
    $('#myFeedback').html( errorThrown );
  }
    });
});
});
</script>
```

==>in your python flask code

```
@app.route("/processlist",methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def processlist():
  myinput=request.form.getlist('listinput[]') # here you add [] at the end
  return '<br>'.join(myinput) # shows the total input
```